# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. despite SPN registration being successful

Tags: kerberos, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have 3 servers:

- Server1 - Remote Server
- Server2 - SQL Server
- Server3 - SQL Server

The SQL Service on both SQL Servers run as a domain user, and I have checked the logs and can confirm they are both SPN registered.

On Server2 I can run locally the following without any problems

```
Select * from Server3.master.sys.servers
```

On Server3 I can run locally the following without any problems

```
Select * from Server2.master.sys.servers
```

On Server1 if I open SSMS and connect to Server3, I can run the following query without any problems

```
Select * from Server2.master.sys.servers
```

But if on Server1 I open SSMS and connect to Server2 and run the following query

```
Select * from Server3.master.sys.servers
```

I get:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I have checked:

- All Servers are allowed to delegate KERBEROS
- Domain user that the SQL Service's are running as are allowed to delegate KERBEROS.
- The domain user I am logging into is not marked as 'Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated.
- The linked Server has security setting 'Be made using the login's current security context'

I have also tried running the Kerberos Configuration Manager on Server1, connected to both Server 2 & 3 with it and it shows everything as being configured correctly.

Comment: What form of delegation have you configured between server2 and server3? This should be constrained: server2 allows delegation to SPN of server3.